# How about adding how long till the bounty expired in the list of questions with a bounty?

Tags: feature-request, questions, bounties

How about adding how long till the bounty expired in the list of questions with a bounty?

Like this:

[image: proposal]

**EDIT**

I am aware that you can see the expiration time when you click the question, but this seams better way to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Sort by shortest time left (if it doesn't already say this) and add a simple HH:NN similar to the # of views somewhere.  Not cluttery at all.

Comment: That's even better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this change because I think it creates to much noise on the list of questions.  Especially since it is in red.

In my opinion the number of days and hours before a bounty expires is not very important in deciding which featured question to put an answer down for.  If you have an answer, post it.

I suggest this change doesn't get made.

Comment: It is in red to make the request visible. Black is good as well.

Comment: @VJo, I understand your request and it is perfectly logical, I am just not sure it worth filling up the results with those additional details.

Comment: Then what is the point in knowing when the bounty expires? You do get it when you click on a question with a bounty